# GROUP column where other column condition with AND

Tags: mysql

I'm not the man of words, but I think the following example will help to show what I want:

When I execute this:

```
SELECT      schritt5_id,
            liste_id                
FROM        schritt5    
JOIN        els_fehler_zo
ON          els_fehler_zo.schritt5_id = schritt5.id        
JOIN        liste
ON          liste.id = els_fehler_zo.liste_id    
WHERE       els_fehler_zo.liste_id  = 1
      OR    els_fehler_zo.liste_id  = 8    
ORDER BY    schritt5_id ASC;
```

I get this:

```
schritt5_id | liste_id
3             1
3             8
6             8
11            8
15            8
25            1
28            1
420           1
421           8
422           1
422           8
423           1
423           8
426           8
438           1
```

Now I want to select all the schritt5_id rows, which have the liste_id 8 AND 1.
I was trying to keep it simple and changed the OR with an AND but this is wrong.
Now I've changed the query to this:

```
SELECT      schritt5_id,
            liste_id,
            GROUP_CONCAT(liste.id ORDER BY liste.id SEPARATOR ' | ') AS cellValue          
FROM        schritt5
JOIN        els_fehler_zo
ON          els_fehler_zo.schritt5_id = schritt5.id    
JOIN        liste
ON          liste.id = els_fehler_zo.liste_id
WHERE       els_fehler_zo.liste_id  = 1
      OR    els_fehler_zo.liste_id  = 8
GROUP BY    schritt5_id
ORDER BY    schritt5_id ASC;
```

And the result is this:

```
schritt5_id  |  liste_id  | cellValue
3              1               1 | 8
6              8               8
11             8               8
15             8               8
25             1               1
28             1               1
420            1               1
421            8               8
422            1               1 | 8
423            1               1 | 8
426            8               8
438            1               1
```

What I actually want to get is this:

```
schritt5_id  |  liste_id  | cellValue
3              1               1 | 8
422            1               1 | 8
423            1               1 | 8
```

When I Join the table with it self like this:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      els_fehler_zo
JOIN      els_fehler_zo a
ON        a.schritt5_id = els_fehler_zo.schritt5_id
      AND a.liste_id   != els_fehler_zo.liste_id
WHERE       a.liste_id    = 1
      AND  els_fehler_zo.liste_id    = 8        
      OR   els_fehler_zo.liste_id    = 8
      AND  a.liste_id    = 1       
GROUP BY  a.schritt5_id;
```

Is there a other way to do it, without joining the table with it self. Because, if I want to search for liste_id 8 AND 1 AND 2 AND 3 ans so on... that means I have to join it every time with it self.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `HAVING` clause. `HAVING` clause is used to restrict the results returned by the `GROUP BY` clause. `WHERE` is applied before `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` is applied after (and can filter on aggregates).

`HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` will return rows with count greater than equal to 2 which you were asking for.

```
SELECT      schritt5_id,
            liste_id,
            GROUP_CONCAT(liste.id ORDER BY liste.id SEPARATOR ' | ') AS cellValue          
FROM        schritt5
JOIN        els_fehler_zo
ON          els_fehler_zo.schritt5_id = schritt5.id    
JOIN        liste
ON          liste.id = els_fehler_zo.liste_id
WHERE       els_fehler_zo.liste_id  = 1
      OR    els_fehler_zo.liste_id  = 8
GROUP BY    schritt5_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 
ORDER BY    schritt5_id ASC;
```

A Sample fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d857/3

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please describe how this solves the user's problem so that future users can learn.

Comment: if I add another list_id for schritt5_id, like (3,16) than run this, it should only show me 2 entries, but it doesn't: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1308f0/3
so it's not really a AND condition?

Comment: It's because `liste_id = 16` is not in or statement. It is not considering the third row. Look at this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1308f0/6
If you add another `OR` for `liste_id = 16` and restrict the `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` it won't show `schritt5_id =3`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1308f0/5
But if I use only two list_id an set HAVING COUNT(*) = 2, it returns all three enteries, but this is wrong

Comment: It is because you are not giving the `OR` statement for `liste_id = 16`. Therefore, it is not regarded. It will work if you remove all the OR statements in your query for `liste_id`. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1308f0/11

Comment: Trank you I get it, but it‘s not what I was seaching for. I want to search for specific liste_id.